# Iterating Over Pandas Dataframe Without Overwriting Previous

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops

First post here seeking solution that I have not been able to solve. I'm essentially trying to iterate over a pandas dataframe without overwriting the previous. Currently, I've got code that gets the first instance but fails to iterate over the next set of "values". See below. Any help is much appreciated!!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# load csv data
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\data.csv")

# convert csv data to pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Date", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5"]
```

Main Code:

```
for n in range(1,10):
    df[n] = pd.Series(["X" if df.iat[x,y] == n else "" for y in range(1,6) for x in range(0,4)])
```

Incorrect Output Table:

| Date | B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | B5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/22/19 | 2 | 3 | 38 | 39 | 40 |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8/25/19 | 5 | 8 | 16 | 20 | 25 |  |  |  |  | X |  |  |  |
| 8/27/19 | 3 | 4 | 19 | 35 | 39 |  |  | X |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8/29/19 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 15 | 19 | X |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

***CORRECT Output Table:***

| Date | B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | B5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/22/19 | 2 | 3 | 38 | 39 | 40 |  | X | **X** |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8/25/19 | 5 | 8 | 16 | 20 | 25 |  |  |  |  | X |  |  | **X** |
| 8/27/19 | 3 | 4 | 19 | 35 | 39 |  |  | X | **X** |  |  |  |  |
| 8/29/19 | 1 | 2 | 6 | 15 | 19 | X | **X** |  |  |  | **X** |  |  |

I hope this makes sense. Thank you!!
:)

Comment: Can you explain what it is exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: One potential issue: you are iterating through your entire original DataFrame which is 4x5, but there are only 4 rows available to each new column you create - this means you're assigning 20 values to a new column with only 4 rows

Comment: n columns are numbers whereas B1-B5 are winning numbers of a lotto dataset. looking for code that identifies the winning numbers into a new table of n columns for later use.  n columns actually go to 52 but for the sake of the this post, i've reduced the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function will make things easier: whenever you make a new column, you iterate through each row of the DataFrame, and each row of your new column is set to "X" if the column value is contained in the row being considered. To avoid overwriting anything, you can index the DataFrame by `"Date"`, and only apply this function to the first 5 columns of the DataFrame.

```
for n in range(1,10):
    df[n] = df.iloc[:,:5].apply(lambda x: "X" if n in x.values else "", axis=1)
```

Result:

```
df
         B1  B2  B3  B4  B5  1  2  3  4  5  6 7  8 9
Date                                                
8/22/19   2   3  38  39  40     X  X                
8/25/19   5   8  16  20  25              X       X  
8/27/19   3   4  19  35  39        X  X             
8/29/19   1   2   6  15  19  X  X           X
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try not use for loop and apply

```
s = df.filter(like='B').stack()
s = pd.crosstab(s.index.get_level_values(level=0),s).replace({0:'',1:'X'})
s.columns = s.columns.astype(str)
out = s.reindex(columns = df.columns).combine_first(df)
          Date   B1   B2    B3    B4    B5  1  2  3  4  5  6 7  8
row_0                                                            
0      8/22/19  2.0  3.0  38.0  39.0  40.0     X  X              
1      8/25/19  5.0  8.0  16.0  20.0  25.0              X       X
2      8/27/19  3.0  4.0  19.0  35.0  39.0        X  X           
3      8/29/19  1.0  2.0   6.0  15.0  19.0  X  X           X
```